# Search text from multiple columns using entity framework

Tags: frameworks, entity

I want to implement a search box on my website to search text from multiple columns in the database.  I am using entity framework. Performance is a big concern for me. So the search must be fast. I haven't done anything like this before. So can someone please give me some idea where I can get started.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this easily using a LINQ query as follows:

```
var matchingProducts = context.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("SearchValue") || p.Description.Contains("SearchValue"));
```

I generally find performance of the generated SQL query to be acceptable.